# Add key/value to json object

Tags: json, jq

I have a json object stored in a shell variable `json`:

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "array": [
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "thing": true
        },
        {
            "name": "baz",
            "thing": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to add a new key (lets call it `new_key`) to both objects within `array`.  I can do the following:

```
$ jq '.array[] + {"new_key": 0}' <<<"$json"
{
  "name": "bar",
  "thing": true,
  "new_key": 0
}
{
  "name": "baz",
  "thing": false,
  "new_key": 0
}
```

However that only returns the array array and not the entire object.  How could I either modify the variable in place or return the entire object?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$ jq '.array[] += { new_key: 0 }' <<<"$json"
{
  "name": "foo",
  "array": [
    {
      "name": "bar",
      "thing": true,
      "new_key": 0
    },
    {
      "name": "baz",
      "thing": false,
      "new_key": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

That is, use `+=` in place of `+`. You want to modify the array, not extract it and add to it.

Or, if you want to hard-code the key in the `jq` expression put pass the value on the command line:

```bash
jq --argjson newval "$somevalue" '.array[] += { new_key: $newval }' <<<"$json"
```

Or neater, using `$ARGS.named`:

```bash
jq --argjson new_key "$somevalue" '.array[] += $ARGS.named' <<<"$json"
```

Change `--argjson` to just `--arg` if the value you are adding is a string.